# UIButton + textView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a text view which have multi lines of data means scrolling.I also need to add feature of tapping on text area that will perform some action.

So to add this feature i placed a button over textview.All seems well but i am not able to scroll text view now because i placed the button.

Please help me or suggest me the way so i can achieve both feature scrolling + tapping to perform some action

this i also tried

```
[mybutton setTitle:@"dfsmnjksnfksndfkjsfkjsdkfjskdfjkdsjfkdsjfksjfkjsdknsmvnxcklvnlk;xvkgn'igsdmvkl'smv,ms,qdaasdasdsadasdvmsklmklvmlkdjffjksjksfkjhksdfjksjfksjfksjfksjdfkdjsfkdsjfkdjfksjdfkjsdfkjsdfkjskfjslfjslkfjlsdjflkdsjfklsjflksdjklsjkdsjfkjdfkjdsfkldskflsdfjsdfl" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mybutton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
```

Comment: Actually, what do you want to do?

Comment: you can add textView as a subview of button.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [gesture recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically UITapGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `UIButton` what you can do is use

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method to detect if user has touch the `UITextView`. You can use it as below:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if( [touch view] == yourTextView)
    {
       // put the code you have written on button action.
    }
}
```